# nodejs server.address() method returns result before 'listening' event emitted

Tags: javascript, node.js

If you want to get the address(host and port) information when you start a server in Node, you possibly would do:

```
const server = http.createServer()
server.listen(() => {
  console.log(`Running on port: ${server.address().port}`)
})
```

The [Doc](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_address) has also said that server.address() should only be called until 'listening' event has been emitted

But if you try this:

```
const server = http.createServer()
server.listen()
console.log(server.address())
```

It still logs out the actual address instead of `null`, why?

Comment: That you should not do it doesn't mean it doesn't work.

Comment: @PeterMader So I'm curious about when will these lines of code fail

Comment: It's not guaranteed to work. It will fail when the server can't be created because the port is occupied or when the system is under load or when the weather isn't right or for any number of other reasons. Don't write your code like this and don't jump to conclusions from undocumented behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `server.listen()` method is asynchronous and may not have everything completely setup by the time you call `console.log(server.address())` (as with your second example).

Your second example is logging the actual address at the time it is executed (which is `null`) because it is called before the server has completed it's setup. This is why you are able to provide a callback method as an argument

```
server.listen(() => {
    console.log('Running on port: ${server.address().port}');
});
```

This allows you to do any sort of operations that require the server to be listening to be executed after it is guaranteed that the server is up and listening.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen) of `server.listen()`

> This function is asynchronous. When the server has been bound, 'listening' event will be emitted.

So

```
const server = http.createServer()
server.listen()
console.log(server.address())
```

Still logs out the actual address.